# Get raw data from the previous step in Zapier

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

In my Zapier CLI app, I need to receive raw data from the previous step. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

This isn't something that's possible. For security reasons, your app can only access data that a user has explicitly provided (via `bundle.inputData`). If it's important to the function of your app, you can have a `dict` type that accepts arbitrary input, but it'll be hard to justify that as a need for your app.

If you'd like to discuss further, I'd reach out to `partners@zapier.com` and we can talk to you about it!